# Bypass closed ports with another server, without routing all data

Tags: linux, networking, routing, linux-networking, port-forwarding

I have two Linux servers. Server A hosts various services, including a website, and has good internet (~500mb/s). However, server A is behind an ISP that does not allow me to open ports. Server B currently holds no services, and I can open ports on it. However, it's internet connection is very slow compared to server A. There is a domain (lets use "mysite.com") that points to B. I also have various devices (PCs, smartphones, etc.) that want to connect to server A. For testing, I have Laptop C, which wants to access a website hosted on Server A through a public wifi network.

While I could route all traffic from A through B to expose A's services, I would be restricted by B's poor network. I want to point laptop C to "mysite.com", and have B somehow "pass" the connection off to A, allowing A and C to directly communicate without being restricted by B's slow connection. I would prefer not to have to install any special software on C - I want  A to be easily accessible through any web browser.

If it is not possible to do this with no extra software on C, is it possible to use Wireguard to accomplish the same affect, or will all traffic have to be routed through server B?

Server A is running Arch Linux and Server B Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: Can you expand on this in your question: *`While I could route all traffic from A through B to expose A's services, `*